# Next js. Cannot find module "./filename.jpeg"

Tags: async-await, img, next.js, multer, fs

сражаюсь с проблемой уже полнедели.

Пользователю открывается модальное окно, где он вносит информацию (название и описание) о плейлисте, и его изображение. При нажатии на кнопку вся информация вносится в базу данных, а изображение сперва обрабатывается с помощью sharp.js, и сохраняется с помощью multer.

После закрытия модального окна пользователь видит перед собой список имеющихся у него плейлистов. Изначально плейлисты получаются с помощью getServerSideProps, вносятся в стейт и , после, стейт будет обновляться до тех пор, пока пользователь не покинет страницу. Стейт являет собой массив объектов, каждый из которых - информация о плейлисте. Информация о каждом плейлисте передается в специальный компонент через пропсы.

В компоненте плейлиста присутствует компонент Image (идущий из коробки next). В src я получаю изображение с помощью `require(.../${avatar})`. При первом рендере страницы, а также при добавлении нового плейлиста с дефолтной картинкой (которая гарантированно есть в папке) всё работает. **Однако при добавлении плейлиста с пользовательской картинкой страница ломается и выкидывает ошибку *'cannot find module ./название-картинки.jpeg'*, а затем через секунды две-три ошибка исчезает и висит белый экран.**

**Страница Playlists.tsx**

```
  const Playlists: React.FC<PlaylistsProps> = ({ user, playlists }) => {
  const [playlistList, setPlaylistList] = React.useState(playlists);
  const [isModalActive, setIsModalActive] = React.useState(false);
  const handleAddPlaylistClick = () => {
    setIsModalActive(true);
  };

  const handleUploadedClick = () => {
    alert("Uploaded playlist");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={clsx({
          [styles.mask]: isModalActive,
        })}
      />
      <PlaylistModal
        active={isModalActive}
        modalClose={setIsModalActive}
        setPlaylistList={setPlaylistList}
      />
      <main className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.main}>
          <Header name={user.userName!} avatar={user.avatarUrl!} />
          <Aside />
          <div className={styles.title}>
            <div className={styles.picture}>
              <Image
                src="/logo/logo-love-1000.png"
                width={150}
                height={150}
                alt="logo"
              />
            </div>
            <div className={styles.text}>
              <span>Playlists</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <section className={styles.playlists_wrapper}>
            <ul className={styles.playlists}>
              <li
                onClick={handleAddPlaylistClick}
                className={clsx(styles.playlist, styles.compulsory)}
              >
                <svg
                  viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                  className={clsx(styles.avatar, styles.svg)}
                >
                  <path d="m256 512c-141.164062 0-256-114.835938-256-256s114.835938-256 256-256 256 114.835938 256 256-114.835938 256-256 256zm0-480c-123.519531 0-224 100.480469-224 224s100.480469 224 224 224 224-100.480469 224-224-100.480469-224-224-224zm0 0" />
                  <path d="m368 272h-224c-8.832031 0-16-7.167969-16-16s7.167969-16 16-16h224c8.832031 0 16 7.167969 16 16s-7.167969 16-16 16zm0 0" />
                  <path d="m256 384c-8.832031 0-16-7.167969-16-16v-224c0-8.832031 7.167969-16 16-16s16 7.167969 16 16v224c0 8.832031-7.167969 16-16 16zm0 0" />
                </svg>
                <span className={styles.name}>Add new playlist</span>
              </li>
              <li
                onClick={handleUploadedClick}
                className={clsx(styles.playlist, styles.compulsory)}
              >
                <svg
                  className={clsx(styles.svg, styles.avatar)}
                  version="1.1"
                  viewBox="0 0 490.667 490.667"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M245.333,0C110.059,0,0,110.059,0,245.333s110.059,245.333,245.333,245.333s245.333-110.059,245.333-245.333
S380.608,0,245.333,0z M245.333,469.333c-123.52,0-224-100.48-224-224s100.48-224,224-224s224,100.48,224,224
S368.853,469.333,245.333,469.333z"
                  />

                  <path
                    d="M245.333,106.667c-5.888,0-10.667,4.779-10.667,10.667v256c0,5.888,4.779,10.667,10.667,10.667S256,379.221,256,373.333
v-256C256,111.445,251.221,106.667,245.333,106.667z"
                  />

                  <path
                    d="M338.219,195.115l-85.333-85.333c-4.16-4.16-10.923-4.16-15.083,0l-85.333,85.333c-4.16,4.16-4.16,10.923,0,15.083
c4.16,4.16,10.923,4.16,15.083,0l77.781-77.781l77.781,77.803c2.091,2.069,4.821,3.115,7.552,3.115
c2.731,0,5.461-1.045,7.552-3.136C342.379,206.037,342.379,199.275,338.219,195.115z"
                  />
                </svg>

                <span className={styles.name}>Uploaded songs</span>
              </li>
              {playlistList.map((obj, id: number) => (
                <Playlist key={id} name={obj.name} avatar={obj.avatarUrl} />
              ))}
            </ul>
          </section>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
  try {
    const user = await checkAuth(ctx);

    if (!user) {
      return {
        props: {},
        redirect: {
          permanent: false,
          destination: "/auth/login",
        },
      };
    }
    if (user.genrePreferences?.length == 0) {
      return {
        props: {},
        redirect: {
          permanent: false,
          destination: "/welcome",
        },
      };
    }
    const playlists = await Api(ctx).getPlaylists();

    return {
      props: {
        playlists,
        user,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error);
  }
};
```

**PlaylistModal.tsx (модалка)**

```
const PlaylistModal: React.FC<PlaylistModalProps> = ({
  active,
  modalClose,
  setPlaylistList,
}) => {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [imageFile, setImageFile] = React.useState<File>();
  const [playlistInfo, setPlayListInfo] = React.useState<PlaylistInfo>({
    name: "",
    description: "",
  });

  const sendInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      if (imageFile) {
        formData.append("avatar", imageFile);
      } else {
        formData.append("avatar", "");
      }
      formData.append("name", playlistInfo.name);
      formData.append("description", playlistInfo.description);
      const result = await Api().createPlaylist(formData);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleInfoChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent) => {
    setPlayListInfo({
      ...playlistInfo,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  const handleImageChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (target.files) {
      const file = target.files[0];
      if (file) {
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        setImageUrl(imageUrl);
        setImageFile(file);
        target.value = "";
      }
    }
  };

  const handleSubmitClick = async () => {
    try {
      const newPlaylist = await sendInfo();
      setPlayListInfo({
        name: "",
        description: "",
      });
      setImageFile(undefined);
      setImageUrl("");

      modalClose(false);
      setPlaylistList((prevState) => [...prevState, newPlaylist]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(styles.modal_wrapper, {
        [styles.modal_active]: active,
      })}
    >
      <div className={styles.modal}>
        <svg
          onClick={() => modalClose(false)}
          className={styles.close}
          width="30pt"
          height="30pt"
          viewBox="0 0 511.995 511.995"
        >
          <path
            d="M437.126,74.939c-99.826-99.826-262.307-99.826-362.133,0C26.637,123.314,0,187.617,0,256.005
            s26.637,132.691,74.993,181.047c49.923,49.923,115.495,74.874,181.066,74.874s131.144-24.951,181.066-74.874
            C536.951,337.226,536.951,174.784,437.126,74.939z M409.08,409.006c-84.375,84.375-221.667,84.375-306.042,0
            c-40.858-40.858-63.37-95.204-63.37-153.001s22.512-112.143,63.37-153.021c84.375-84.375,221.667-84.355,306.042,0
            C493.435,187.359,493.435,324.651,409.08,409.006z"
          />

          <path
            d="M341.525,310.827l-56.151-56.071l56.151-56.071c7.735-7.735,7.735-20.29,0.02-28.046
            c-7.755-7.775-20.31-7.755-28.065-0.02l-56.19,56.111l-56.19-56.111c-7.755-7.735-20.31-7.755-28.065,0.02
            c-7.735,7.755-7.735,20.31,0.02,28.046l56.151,56.071l-56.151,56.071c-7.755,7.735-7.755,20.29-0.02,28.046
            c3.868,3.887,8.965,5.811,14.043,5.811s10.155-1.944,14.023-5.792l56.19-56.111l56.19,56.111
            c3.868,3.868,8.945,5.792,14.023,5.792c5.078,0,10.175-1.944,14.043-5.811C349.28,331.117,349.28,318.562,341.525,310.827z"
          />
        </svg>
        <div className={styles.title}>
          <img
            src="/logo/logo-happy-1000.png"
            className={styles.pic}
            alt="logo"
          />
          <span className={styles.text}>Create the playlist</span>
        </div>
        <form className={styles.form}>
          <div className={styles.info}>
            <label htmlFor="upload" className={styles.avatar}>
              <div className={styles.picture}>
                <img
                  width={300}
                  height={300}
                  className={styles.image}
                  src={
                    imageUrl != ""
                      ? imageUrl
                      : "/defaults/playlist-default.jpeg"
                  }
                  alt="avatar"
                />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.text}>
                <span> Choose the avatar</span>
              </div>
            </label>
            <input
              onChange={handleImageChange}
              id="upload"
              className={styles.upload}
              type="file"
              name="avatar"
            />
            <div className={styles.input_info}>
              <div className={styles.input_block}>
                <span className={styles.input_title}>
                  Enter the name of your new playlist:
                </span>
                <input
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Name..."
                  className={clsx(styles.input, styles.input_name)}
                  type="text"
                  value={playlistInfo.name}
                  onChange={handleInfoChange}
                ></input>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.input_block}>
                <span className={styles.input_title}>
                  Enter the description of your new playlist:
                </span>
                <textarea
                  name="description"
                  value={playlistInfo.description}
                  placeholder="Description..."
                  className={clsx(styles.input, styles.descr)}
                  onChange={handleInfoChange}
                ></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Button
            onClick={handleSubmitClick}
            color={["white", "#a406cb", "none"]}
            size={[200, 50]}
            className={styles.submit}
          >
            Lets go
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlaylistModal;
```

**Компонент Playlist.tsx**

```
const Playlist: React.FC<PlaylistProps> = ({ name, avatar }) => {
  const handlePlaylistClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement>) => {
    if (e.target.tagName !== "svg" && e.target.tagName !== "path") {
      alert(`Playlist named '${name}'`);
    }
  };
  const handleEditClick = () => {
    alert(`Edit '${name}'`);
  };

  const handleDeleteClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<SVGSVGElement>) => {
    alert(`Delete '${name}'`);
  };

  return (
    <li onClick={handlePlaylistClick} className={styles.playlist}>
      <Image
        className={styles.avatar}
        width={50}
        height={50}
        src={require(`/server/avatars/playlists/${avatar}`)}
        alt="playlist-avatar"
      />
      <span className={styles.name}>{name}</span>
      <div className={styles.tools}>
        <svg
          onClick={handleEditClick}
          width="30pt"
          height="30pt"
          className={styles.tool}
          viewBox="-15 -15 484.00019 484"
        >
          <path d="m401.648438 18.234375c-24.394532-24.351563-63.898438-24.351563-88.292969 0l-22.101563 22.222656-235.269531 235.144531-.5.503907c-.121094.121093-.121094.25-.25.25-.25.375-.625.746093-.871094 1.121093 0 .125-.128906.125-.128906.25-.25.375-.371094.625-.625 1-.121094.125-.121094.246094-.246094.375-.125.375-.25.625-.378906 1 0 .121094-.121094.121094-.121094.25l-52.199219 156.96875c-1.53125 4.46875-.367187 9.417969 2.996094 12.734376 2.363282 2.332031 5.550782 3.636718 8.867188 3.625 1.355468-.023438 2.699218-.234376 3.996094-.625l156.847656-52.324219c.121094 0 .121094 0 .25-.121094.394531-.117187.773437-.285156 1.121094-.503906.097656-.011719.183593-.054688.253906-.121094.371094-.25.871094-.503906 1.246094-.753906.371093-.246094.75-.621094 1.125-.871094.125-.128906.246093-.128906.246093-.25.128907-.125.378907-.246094.503907-.5l257.371093-257.371094c24.351563-24.394531 24.351563-63.898437 0-88.289062zm-232.273438 353.148437-86.914062-86.910156 217.535156-217.535156 86.914062 86.910156zm-99.15625-63.808593 75.929688 75.925781-114.015626 37.960938zm347.664062-184.820313-13.238281 13.363282-86.917969-86.917969 13.367188-13.359375c14.621094-14.609375 38.320312-14.609375 52.945312 0l33.964844 33.964844c14.511719 14.6875 14.457032 38.332031-.121094 52.949218zm0 0" />
        </svg>
        <svg
          onClick={handleDeleteClick}
          width="30pt"
          height="30pt"
          className={styles.tool}
          viewBox="-40 0 427 427.00131"
        >
          <path d="m232.398438 154.703125c-5.523438 0-10 4.476563-10 10v189c0 5.519531 4.476562 10 10 10 5.523437 0 10-4.480469 10-10v-189c0-5.523437-4.476563-10-10-10zm0 0" />
          <path d="m114.398438 154.703125c-5.523438 0-10 4.476563-10 10v189c0 5.519531 4.476562 10 10 10 5.523437 0 10-4.480469 10-10v-189c0-5.523437-4.476563-10-10-10zm0 0" />
          <path d="m28.398438 127.121094v246.378906c0 14.5625 5.339843 28.238281 14.667968 38.050781 9.285156 9.839844 22.207032 15.425781 35.730469 15.449219h189.203125c13.527344-.023438 26.449219-5.609375 35.730469-15.449219 9.328125-9.8125 14.667969-23.488281 14.667969-38.050781v-246.378906c18.542968-4.921875 30.558593-22.835938 28.078124-41.863282-2.484374-19.023437-18.691406-33.253906-37.878906-33.257812h-51.199218v-12.5c.058593-10.511719-4.097657-20.605469-11.539063-28.03125-7.441406-7.421875-17.550781-11.5546875-28.0625-11.46875h-88.796875c-10.511719-.0859375-20.621094 4.046875-28.0625 11.46875-7.441406 7.425781-11.597656 17.519531-11.539062 28.03125v12.5h-51.199219c-19.1875.003906-35.394531 14.234375-37.878907 33.257812-2.480468 19.027344 9.535157 36.941407 28.078126 41.863282zm239.601562 279.878906h-189.203125c-17.097656 0-30.398437-14.6875-30.398437-33.5v-245.5h250v245.5c0 18.8125-13.300782 33.5-30.398438 33.5zm-158.601562-367.5c-.066407-5.207031 1.980468-10.21875 5.675781-13.894531 3.691406-3.675781 8.714843-5.695313 13.925781-5.605469h88.796875c5.210937-.089844 10.234375 1.929688 13.925781 5.605469 3.695313 3.671875 5.742188 8.6875 5.675782 13.894531v12.5h-128zm-71.199219 32.5h270.398437c9.941406 0 18 8.058594 18 18s-8.058594 18-18 18h-270.398437c-9.941407 0-18-8.058594-18-18s8.058593-18 18-18zm0 0" />
          <path d="m173.398438 154.703125c-5.523438 0-10 4.476563-10 10v189c0 5.519531 4.476562 10 10 10 5.523437 0 10-4.480469 10-10v-189c0-5.523437-4.476563-10-10-10zm0 0" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Playlist;
```

**Запрос на сервер**

```
createPlaylist: async(_info: FormData) => {
            try {
                const { data } = await instance.post("/playlists/create", _info, {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                      }
                    } 
                );
                return data;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }      
        },
```

**Обработка и загрузка изображения на сервер**

```
async createPlaylist(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
        if (req.file) {
            try {
                const { id } = req.user!.data;
                const { filename: image } = req.file 
                const filePath = req.file?.path;
                let newFileName: string;
                newFileName = image;
                await sharp(path.resolve(filePath)).resize(150, 150).toFormat('jpeg').toFile(path.resolve(req.file?.destination, "playlists", newFileName)),  (err: any) => {
                    if (err) {
                      throw err;
                    }
                }

                fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
                const obj = {
                    name: req.body.name,
                    description: req.body.description,
                    avatarUrl: newFileName,
                    songs: [],
                    private: false,
                    belongsTo: id,
                }
                const playlistInfo = await Playlist.create(obj);
                res.status(200).json(playlistInfo);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.sendStatus(500);
            }

        } else {
            try {
                const { id } = req.user!.data;
                const obj = {
                    name: req.body.name,
                    description: req.body.description,
                    avatarUrl: "default.jpeg",
                    songs: [],
                    private: false,
                    belongsTo: id,
                };
                const playlistInfo = await Playlist.create(obj);
                res.status(200).json(await playlistInfo.toJSON())

            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Я подозреваю, что подобная ошибка возникает из-за того, что файл не успевает создаться в папке на сервере, и компонент Image требует фактически несуществующую картинку. **Как можно дождаться создания файла на сервере, и только потом обновлять страницу? А если проблема не в этом, то в чём?**

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, переместив изображения из папки "/server/avatars/playlists" в папку "/public/avatars/playlists" и изменив путь до картинки в компоненте Playlist:

```
      <Image
        className={styles.avatar}
        width={50}
        height={50}
        src={`/avatats/playlists/${avatar}`}
        alt="playlist-avatar"
      />
```